# Access Json array data

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a MYSQL query that returns data using PDO::FETCHASSOC.
The array is then encoded using json.encode.

```
$row = $s->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($row);
```

The result is then passed to a javascript script using:

```
var percents = [];
percents.push(<?php get_percent('accantonamenti irreperibili', $pdo)?>);
```

Using console.log I see that percents is:

```
 [[Object { perc_worst="-100", perc_best="-33"}]]
```

Question: how do I get perc_worst and perc_best values assigning them to two different values? percents.perc_worst doesn't work and either percents[0].perc_worst
BTW I can't get why the pair key value is created with = instead of :

Anyone can help??
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont do `.push()`.

Instead, do:

```
var percents = <?php get_percent('accantonamenti irreperibili', $pdo)?>;
```

Try accessing the values by:

```
console.log(percents.perc_worst);
console.log(percents.perc_best);
```

Keep it simple :)

Comment: The array becomes [Object { perc_worst="-100", perc_best="-33"}] (lost the outer square braket) but the values are undefined

Comment: @LelioFaieta Now try `console.log(percents[0].perc_worst)` or `console.log(percents[0].perc_best)`

Comment: was testing it right now... it works. you are right, better keep it simple! :D